# Create ProjectRoles in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rest

this API doesn't have any mention of ProjectRoles
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000078091-How-do-I-use-RBAC-REST-API-?page=37

all the URL endpoints i am getting a 404, site not found for creating any role.

Comment: Is that a feature only of Cloudbees Jenkins Product (not the OSS varaiant) do you need to have the [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) plugin installed?

Comment: We do have the Role-based plugin installed and none of the paths for that RestAPI work. I get 404 for all of them. When i run any of these options , jenkins says unable to process and throws a uuid error - s:
Add Role: curl -X POST localhost:8080/role-strategy/strategy/addRole --data "type=globalRoles&amp;roleName=ADM&amp;permissionIds=hudson.model.Item.Discover,hudson.model.Item.ExtendedRead&amp;overwrite=true"
Assign Role: curl -X POST localhost:8080/role-strategy/strategy/assignRole

Comment: Then maybe it's a feature of the [CloudBees CI product](https://docs.cloudbees.com/downloads) and not [Jenkins OSS](https://www.jenkins.io/download/) ? What product are you using?

Comment: opensource jenkins